# Find closest numerical value in Powershell arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell-2.0, windows-7-x64

**Q:** I'm looking for a more elegant way to get the closest match of a numerical from an array.
I may have over-complicated things here

### Input

```
## A given array A where to search in
$a = (16/10),(16/9),(4/3),(5/4),(21/10),(21/9)  

## A given value B which should be searched for in array A (closest match)
$b = 16/11
```

### Desired output

```
"Closest value to 16/11 is 4/3"
```

### My current code to solve the problem

```
## New array C for the differences of array A - B
$c = $a | %{  [math]::abs($_ - $b) } 

## Measure array C to get lowest value D
$d = $c | measure -Minimum

## Get position E of value D in array C
$e = [array]::IndexOf($c, $d.minimum)

## Position E correlates to array A
echo "Closest value to $b is $($a[$e])
```

#### Remarks

- It don't has to be an array if a hash table or something else suits better
- My current code outputs decimals like `1.33333` instead of fractions `4/3`. It would be nice to output the fraction
- Short code is always better

Comment: For the desired output, shouldn't the closest value be 4/3, and not 16/10?

Comment: @RyanBemrose Oh, of course. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = (16/10),(16/9),(4/3),(5/4),(21/10),(21/9) 
$b = 16/11
$oldval = $b - $a[0]
$Final = $a[0]
if($oldval -lt 0){$oldval = $oldval * -1}
$a | %{$val = $b - $_
if($val -lt 0 ){$val = $val * -1}
if ($val -lt $oldval){
$oldval = $val
$Final = $_} }
Write-host "$Final is the closest to $b"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## A given array A where to search in
$a = '16/10','16/9','4/3','5/4','21/10','21/9'

## A given value B which should be searched for in array A (closest match)
$b = '16/11'

$numericArray = ($a | % { Invoke-Expression $_ })
$test = Invoke-Expression $b
$best = 0
$diff = [double]::MaxValue
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $numericArray.count; $i++) {
    $newdiff = [math]::abs($numericArray[$i] - $test)
    if ($newdiff -lt $diff) {
        $diff = $newdiff
        $best = $i
    }
}

"Closest value to $b is $($a[$best])"
```

The big difference here is that the inputs are strings and not numbers, so we can preserve the fractions.

**Security note**: Don't use this if the inputs are from a user, as passing user-generated strings to Invoke-Expression is obviously a recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
$diff = $b - $a[0]
$min_index = 0
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $a.count; $i++)
{
   $new_diff = $b - $a[$i]
   if ($new_diff -lt $diff)
   {
      $diff = $new_diff
      $min_index = $i
   }
}

Write-Output "Closest value to $b is $($a[$min_index])"
```

Powershell dose not support fraction values...

Answer (score 0):

```
    ## A given array A where to search in
$a = (16/10),(16/9),(4/3),(5/4),(21/10),(21/9)  

## A given value B which should be searched for in array A (closest match)
$b = 16/11

<#Create a new-Object , we'll use this to store the results in the Foreach Loop#>
$values = [Pscustomobject] @{
                             'result'    = @()
                             'a-values'  = @()
                            }
    
 foreach($aa in $a)
                  {         #round to 2 decimal places and then subtract 
                            #store the result at the 'a-value' used to create that result
                   $values.result += [MATH]::Abs(    [Math]::Round($B,2)`
                                                    -[Math]::Round($aa,2)`
                                                 )                         
                   $values."a-values" += $aa
                  }

# sort ascending and then this gets me the number closest to Zero
$lookFor = $($values.result | Sort-Object )[0]

#the result of the Number closest to $b = 16/11                          
$endresult = $values.'a-values'[  $values.result.indexof($lookfor)  ]

Write-host "the number closest to '$b' is '$endresult'"

Remove-Variable values
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a oneliner sorting with distance function:

```
($a | Sort-Object { [Math]::abs($_ - $b) })[0]
```

Returning a fraction is not possible in this case because e.g. `16/10` is immediately converted to a decimal.